# I want to have both computeIfPresent and putIfAbsent into one atomic function

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, concurrenthashmap, atomic

```
workObjectMap.computeIfPresent(key, (k,v) -> {
    v.memberIdSet.addAll(memberIdSet);
    v.memberPositionSet.addAll(memberPositionSet);
    return v;
});
// If it.remove() in run() is called at this point,
// there is a risk of the same work being done twice
workObjectMap.putIfAbsent(key, new WorkObjectValue(memberIdSet, memberPositionSet));
```

I have the above code. In a separate thread I may be removing from the `workObjectMap`. I want an atomic function that modifies the value if the key is present, and if its not, it puts the key/value.

In my current code, there is a chance that the remove will happen in between the `computeIfPresent` and `putIfAbsent` so that the same item that was already added to the map, would be added again.

How do I block any removes in between these 2 method calls? (`computeIfPresent` and `putIfAbsent`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Map.compute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
workObjectMap.compute(key, (k,v) -> {
    if (v == null) return new WorkObjectValue(memberIdSet, memberPositionSet);
    v.memberIdSet.addAll(memberIdSet);
    v.memberPositionSet.addAll(memberPositionSet);
    return v;
});
```

Note that [the `ConcurrentHashMap` Javadoc explicitly states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) that this is atomic.

Comment: Of course! Thank you. I misunderstood the documentation when I initially read it.